# MySQL: what is the meaning of specifying the size when declaring integer datatype? e.g int(2), int(11)

Tags: mysql

As we specify integer size when declaring integer field in MySQL, what is the relevance of it?

Does it impact on the storage of data?

Comment: No,an int in mysql will always be 4 bytes,2^32.The size is just to display the data for certain clients,a hint. you have a number with 5 digits if you specify int(4) only four will be displayed.

Comment: The size works together with the `ZEROFILL` attribute. When the field has this attribute set, MySQL will return the value padded to the left with `0` until the specified size.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html). It explains [everything](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html).

Basically, for integer numbers, the type (`TINYINT`, `SMALLINT` a.s.o.) determines the number of bytes used to store the value and the [range of values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) it can accommodate while the size only tells the minimum number of characters used to display the value. The size is informative, it tells how the data is formatted by default.

The size works together with the ZEROFILL attribute. When an integer field has this attribute set, MySQL will return the value padded to the left with 0 until the specified size.

Even if the documentation says the size *"indicates the maximum display width for integer types"*, I couldn't find any client that truncates the value when it doesn't fit in the specified size. The size is just a hint that the values do not need more than *size* characters to be displayed but it does not enforce anything. The field can store and will store without any error or warning any value that fits in the range determined by the type.

For other types (`FLOAT`, `CHAR`s) the size has more importance and it says how much [storage space](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) is used to store a value of that type.

Answer (score -1):

I think specifying the size is important because you would limit width of int a user will practically see hence other remaining width spaces will be filled up by zeros.

And two,No the storage size remains 4bytes.